# Why are there no nonzero morphisms between these two sheaves?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $C$ be a nodal curve, $w\in C$ a node, and let $p: C'\rightarrow C$ be its normalization, with $p^{-1}(w) = \{z_1,z_2\}$.

Let $\Omega_{C',z_1}$ be the stalk of the cotangent sheaf of $C'$ at $z_1$.

Why is the following true?
$$\text{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_{C,w}}(\Omega_{C',z_1},\mathcal{O}_{C',z_2}(-z_2)) = 0$$
(This is claimed on page 182 in Arbarello-Cornalba-Griffiths "Geometry of Algebraic Curves", Volume 2)